# CSS How to make absolute elemement occupy space

Tags: css, position

I have tabs and I want to use the width of the first tab content as base.
I'm using the position value for the first tab as `relative`, and the rest is `absolute`.
I solved the problem for width but not for height.
you can see the button is placed on top of the content area. How do I handle this case?

Example Link: https://jsfiddle.net/uow2jkzh/2/

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab:nth-child(1) {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

.tab:nth-last-child(1) {
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.tab:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.contents {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .25s;
}

.content.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.content2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="tabs">
        <button data-content="0" class="tab active">London</button>
        <button data-content="1" class="tab">Paris</button>
      </div>

      <div class="contents">
        <div class="content content1 active">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non,
        </div>
        <div class="content content2">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non,
          temporibus quis nihil nam deleniti ut ratione voluptas molestiae quos
          impedit animi corporis velit fugiat distinctio aliquid dicta ducimus.
          Quam, dolorum!
        </div>
      </div>

      <button class="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <script>
      const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
      const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

      function onTabClick() {
        tabs.forEach((tab) => {
          tab.classList.remove('active');
        });

        contents.forEach((content) => {
          content.classList.remove('active');
        });

        const contentIndex = this.dataset.content;

        this.classList.add('active');
        contents[contentIndex].classList.add('active');
      }

      tabs.forEach((tab) => {
        tab.onclick = onTabClick;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i did it using JavaScript. there can be a way to do it using css only.
here's my code if you want to use js.

*i have changed your margin-top to padding-top for get exact height*

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
      const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

      function onTabClick() {
        tabs.forEach((tab) => {
          tab.classList.remove('active');
        });

        contents.forEach((content) => {
          content.classList.remove('active');
        });

        const contentIndex = this.dataset.content;
        this.classList.add('active');
        contents[contentIndex].classList.add('active');
        document.querySelector('.contents').style.height = document.querySelector('.content.active').offsetHeight+'px';
      }

      tabs.forEach((tab) => {
        tab.onclick = onTabClick;
      });
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab:nth-child(1) {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

.tab:nth-last-child(1) {
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.tab:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.contents {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .25s;
}

.content.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.content2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="tabs">
        <button data-content="0" class="tab active">London</button>
        <button data-content="1" class="tab">Paris</button>
      </div>

      <div class="contents">
        <div class="content content1 active">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non,
        </div>
        <div class="content content2">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non,
          temporibus quis nihil nam deleniti ut ratione voluptas molestiae quos
          impedit animi corporis velit fugiat distinctio aliquid dicta ducimus.
          Quam, dolorum!
        </div>
      </div>

      <button class="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, I'll probably use javascript to handle this.
It is a good idea to set the height of the container equal to the height of the active tab.
Thanks a lot, it solved my problem